# Iterate through tokens and find the entity for a token

Tags: stanford-nlp

**Problem**

After running CoreNLP over some text, I want to reconstruct a sentence adding the POS-tag for each Token and grouping the tokens that form an entity.

This could be easily done if there was a way to see which entity a Token belongs to.

**Aproach**

One option I was considering now was going through `sentence.tokens()` and finding the index in a list containing only the Tokens from all the CoreEntityMentions for that sentence. Then I could see which CoreEntityMention that Token belongs to, so I can group them.

Another option could be to look the offsets of each Token in the sentence and compare it to the offset of each CoreEntityMention.

I think the question is similar to what was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689717/is-it-possible-to-get-a-set-of-a-specific-named-entity-tokens-that-comprise-a-ph), but since it was a while ago, maybe the API has changed since.

This is the setup:

```java
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner");

    pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    String text = "Some text with entities goes here";
    CoreDocument coreDoc = new CoreDocument(text);
    // annotate the document
    pipeline.annotate(coreDoc);
    for (CoreSentence sentence : coreDoc.sentences()) {
      // Code goes here
      List<CoreEntityMention> em : sentence.entityMentions();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each token in an entity mention contains an index to which entity mention in the document it corresponds to.

```
cl.get(CoreAnnotations.EntityMentionIndexAnnotation.class);
```

I'll make a note to add a convenience method for this future versions.

Comment: Note this will be null if the token is not in an entity mention.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed!